# Redirect one domain to a subdomain and the other subdomains to www.domain

Tags: .htaccess

I have a main domain to a server and I need redirect  all sub domains to WWW except one and another domain has redirect to another sub domain to first main domain.

Example:

All sub domains have redirect to:

```
www.domain1.com
```

Except:

```
domain2.domain1.com
```

and

```
www.domain2.com
```

Which are redirected to:

```
domain2.domain1.com
```

Thanks for any useful response and excuse me for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

Enable `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain2\.domain1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.domain1.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2\.domain1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://domain2.domain1.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```